Inferring Exact Value Type by Key on an Object With Multiple Value Types
enum KeyEnum {
    A = "A",
    B = "B",
}

type Value = Record<string, Record<any, any>>


const someRecord = { a: { b : "string"} };
const someOtherRecord = { c: { d : 1 } };

const dictionary: Record<string, Value> = {

    [KeyEnum.A]: someRecord,
    [KeyEnum.B]: someOtherRecord,

}

// Record<any, any> instead of { b: string }
const v1 = dictionary[KeyEnum.A].a

// Record<any, any> instead of { d: number }
const v2 = dictionary[KeyEnum.B].c

How would I go about structuring the types and/or dictionary to allow TS to infer the exact value when doing an exact key lookup without generics?
I might be asking too much of TS here, but it would be nice if the caller knew in the IDE that one type is a string and the other type is a number when the key lookup is exact and the object is statically defined.

Sorry about that - done. I think the question is borderline asking too much of TS, but I'm generally curious if something like this is possible.

Sorry it was a typo. I typed it out on my phone while away from the keyboard. That is exactly it - I'll have to read up on how satisfy works.
Feel free to answer the question. Appreciate the insight.

I've fixed the typo and added an answer with links to documentation.

You cannot annotate the dictionary variable's type as Record<string, Value> without throwing away the information about the narrower type of its initializing object literal.  If you want to be sure that dictionary is assignable to that type without widening it to that type, you can use the satisfies operator instead:
const dictionary = {
    [KeyEnum.A]: someRecord,
    [KeyEnum.B]: someOtherRecord,
} satisfies Record<string, Value>

const v1 = dictionary[KeyEnum.A].a
//    ^? const v1: { b: string; }
const v2 = dictionary[KeyEnum.B].c
//    ^? const v2: { d: number; }

Playground link to code

Well, you're declaring the type of dictionary so your example works as expected.
If you want typescript to infer the type of each value in the dictionary but also check it follows a generic structure Record<string, Value>, you can use satisfies like this:
const dictionary = {
    [KeyEnum.A]: someRecord,
    [KeyEnum.B]: someOtherRecord,
} satisfies Record<string, Value>


